# jquery fade hover 4 issues

Tags: jquery, html, css, text, hover

I have four issues with a jquery fade to black on image hover:

1. — The first is a minor issue — there is a black border around the
   images which I can't get rid of.
2. — The second is that occasionaly on hover one of the images
   decreases in size (see attached screenshot)
3. — The third is that I cannot seem to increase the speed of hover
4. — The fourth is that I would like centred text to appear on hover

I am really new to Jquery so any help with ANY of these issues would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Here is the CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
    background:#f5f5f5;
    border-bottom-left:25px;
    border-left-color:#F0EFF1;
    border-left-height:1000px;
    }

#border {
    position:fixed;
    width:37px;
    height:8000px;
    margin-left:-10px;
    margin-top:0px;
    z-index:2000;
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    }

#infoleft
    {   
    position:fixed;
    top:20px;
    left:25px;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.14em;
    line-height:1.2em;
    display:block;
    }

#infoleft ul {
    height:20px;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size: 14.5px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    }

#infoleft ul li { 
    display: inline; 
    padding: 10px;
    }


#inforight
    {   
    position:fixed;
    top:21px;
    right:23px;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size: 14.5px;
    letter-spacing: 1pxem;
    }


#inforight ul {
    height:20px;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.13em;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    }


#images {
    position:absolute;
    left:30px;
    bottom:35px;
    top:100px;
    width:25000px;
    padding-top:80px;
    min-height:500px;



}

img {
    padding:5px;
    height:90%;
}

#images a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  margin-right: 3px;
  /*adjust to your linking*/
}

#images img {
  pading: 5,5,5,5,;
}

img a:hover {
    color:black;
    opacity:1;
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}

a:hover {
    color:#0080ff;
}

#showinfo {
    position:fixed;
    top:150px;
    left:35px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    font-size:15px;
    z-index:2000;
}

#showinfo a {
    color:#000;
}

#showinfo a:hover {
    color:#0080ff;
    cursor:pointer;
}


#projectInfo {
    position: fixed;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    top: 185px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 280px;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 20px 32px 32px 30px;
    height: 280px;
    font-size: 13.5px;
    line-height:1.4em;
    letter-spacing:0.13em;
}
```

And the Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Dean Pauley — Recent work</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script defer src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="showinfo">
<a href="#" id="showProjectInfo"><span id="showhide">[+]</span></a>
</div>
<div id="projectInfo" style="display: block; ">
            <p>News from Nowhere</p>                            
            <p>—</p>
            <p>A response to The Tyranny of Email by John Freeman exploring how the quality of the written word has deteriorated due to the faster methods of digital communication by contrasting it with that of a pre-digital era. The leather bound-book consists of over 3000 different spam emails.

</p>
</div>
<div id="border">
</div>
<div id="infoleft">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Dean Pauley</a></li>
<li>Graphic Design</li>
<li>mail@deanpauley.co.uk</li>
<li>+44(0)7969 652 219</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="inforight">
<ul>
<li><a href="info.html" class="transition">Information</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="images">
<a href="#"><img src="images/img_off.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/Calendar1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/img_off.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/Calendar1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/img_off.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/Calendar1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/img_off.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/Calendar1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/img_off.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/Calendar1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/img_off.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/Calendar1.jpg" /></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").hover(function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({opacity: "0.2"}, '300');
    },
    function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({opacity: "1"}, '300');
    });
  });
</script>

  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("projectinfo").hide();
        $("showprojectinfo").show();
    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $("projectinfo").slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
<script src="js/script.min.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

Screenshots:

[image: Image with unwanted border]

[image: Hover with text]

Comment: For border thing you can try this, add `border:none;` for #images.

Comment: A question apart from your main issue. What do you want to archive with including two different versions of jquery and 'script.js' ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand. Could you explain?

Comment: @DeanPauley He means you are calling the jQuery library twice (src='jquery.js' and "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js") when you only need it once. script.js might be a different plugin, if not the one in the bottom then remove it too.

Comment: can you http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @utoiccam if you scroll to the bottom of the page he want to include another version of jquery "document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"><\/script>')"

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that issue with the images getting smaller happening in my programming, even when i had specifically resized every image perfectly to the exact dimensions and reduced the file size...  Then I discovered that it happens in slideshows if the actual filename of your images has a space or a dash, or some other odd character in it before the format name (that ends in jpeg, gif, png, etc) that is enough to create an error which looks like the image gets larger and smaller and close, like a camera shutter sort of.    If you go back and simply rename the images or delete the spaces, dashes, etc, and reload them that takes care of it and the slides transition as you intended.